# How does someone become a professor who makes break throughs at creating Artificial Intelligence rather than merely analyzes data with known methods?

Tags: phd, artificial-intelligence

How does someone become a professor who makes break throughs creating Artificial Intelligence through deep learning rather than someone who merely knows many ways of analyzing data and write reports?

I want to be the person who made the break through of finding how to do image recognition with high accuracy rather than someone who simply runs image classification algorithms or applies it to a new problem after its invented.

A lot of the data science/statistics professors I know merely analyze data, increase accuracy by a couple of percentage points, but don't really change anything big because they didn't figure out how to generalize the methods to a broader set of things or eliminate some big hurdle to making an AI.

I want to draw the fine line between data analyst, and AI creator. The latter knows everything the former knows but can make machines more or as powerful as humans and pushes the limits of the math and computers.

Some people are merely satisfied with having one dataset analyzed, and settle with not having the algorithms create AIs and I'm not even sure how to classify or figure out who are the ambitious professors who are trying to make breakthroughs in AI versus are just settling with what's already created.

I'm starting to realize the phrase "data scientists" is just a fancy phrase for someone who knows a lot of methods and applies it to write conclusions about data and isn't someone who knows how to make cars autonomous. They're really not very interesting especially if a company is just using them to punch buttons with tensorflow compared to someone who actually knows how to make a leap.

Comment: I think you are pretty confused about how the AI field works.

Comment: Are you suggesting the field is a lot less exciting than I think it is? We're still pretty far away from having 100% accurate video-recognition and autonomous decision making? And even if I had a PhD in AI, I'd be pretty disappointed all day becuase there's not much I can do to make autonomous cars work?

Comment: Find someone who does what you consider to be _successful_ research. Look at their career and research paths. Repeat until you find trends.

Comment: If you want to make autonomous cars work, that would put you in the category of making incremental 1-2% increases in accuracy that you seem to find uninteresting. Science is incremental; there are bigger leaps that occur but these are still often incremental at heart.

Comment: The problems is the 1-2% increases in accuracy are sometimes tuning the hyperparameters, and they spent an entire paper talking about how to increase accuracy on one dataset, and the tuning only works on a specific limited generalizability problem that they haven't solved anything. Change the data, and the accuracy is bad again.

Comment: Minsky's summer project comes to mind: "Solve the problem of image recognition."

Comment: @Numbers In AI, the boundaries between science and engineering are fuzzy. The paper you mention is probably more on the engineering side. Learning Theory, for instance, is more on the science side. Good work is done there regularly, but of course, you do not have an MCTS or deep learning discovery or rediscovery every day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People typically don't become experts overnight. A breakthrough is not done in a single day. New ideas are built on top of a vast knowledge across many disciplines. Professors and other experts have broad and deep knowledge of the subject, but also, importantly, they engage with the subject in many roles: they study the existing knowledge, they test and apply it, they create derivatives, they challenge aspects of the existing knowledge, they teach it, they transform it, they combine it with something else. A new design without applications is useless. A routine application of the same technique is boring. One need both to design new approaches and to promote them to applications in order to be successful in academia.

Now to your main question - how to become such a person. With baby steps. Make yourself a goal for a day, for a week, for a month and for a year. If you are a college student, it may be to complete a homework, to learn a new data analysis technique, to complete a course, and to submit an application to a University of your choice. Then work towards these goals. Good luck!